# Unable to run rake or rails commands (like rails c) - libcrypto error

Tags: ruby, rvm

When attempting to run any rake, rails or bundle commands, I get following error:

```
/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
```

I have tried rvm pkg install openssl, rvm remove 1.9.3, rvm reinstall 1.9.3, reinstall bundler and all gems.  I read on another forum that I may have to uninstall rvm, ruby and rails and start from scratch.  Ugh - really?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read and follow the instructions displayed with:

```
rvm requirements
```

then remove the rvm installed openssl:

```
rm -rf $rvm_path/usr/
```

and reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p194
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up uninstalling everything and reinstalling.